# Одноразова неповторювана дія за значенням "пірнати"

Tags: вибір-слова

Якщо

стрибати - стрибання - **стрибок**, то

пірнати - пірнання - **?**

Спочатку думав, що можна замінити на "стрибок у воду", потім через СУМ дізнався, що `пірнання` - це необов’язково стрибок - можна просто зануритися у воду, і це також `пірнути`.

В анґлійській є слово `dive`.

В російській є слово `нырок`.

[Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/uk-ru/%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) при перекладі з російської каже, що можна так і перекласти: `нирок`, але в [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nyrok) бачу, що це взагалі птах.

[Lingvo](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Translate/en-uk/dive) при перекладі з анґлійської пропонує два непоганих варіанти: `стрибок у воду` (що частково відповідає дійсності) і `занурення`. Ресурс [yenotes](http://yenotes.com) також пропонує варіант [занурення](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/translations/6b8c5dd12ced4accaad5b5a7b1706a06/view/).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zanurjuvatysja) підтверджує, що `занурюватися` - це `Опускатися у воду або в якусь іншу рідину.`

Тобто, в принципі, словосполученням `стрибок у воду` і словом `занурення` можна охопити одноразову неповторювану дію за значенням "пірнати", але може я щось пропускаю? Може, є більш точний відповідник (або навіть однокореннєве слово)?

Comment: знайшла одне-єдине посилання на **пірнок**, щоправда в еротичному контексті, тому вагаюсь, чи можна давати посилання.

Comment: а ось ще один приклад, в нейтральному контексті: ["Два тижні в Сайгоні - ніби **пірнок** на затримку дихання"](http://www.markin.info/uk/blog/113-prygody.html). 
Утім, в словниках не знаходжу такого слова.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko О! Я також шукав "пірнок", але результати такі непевні, що навіть побоявся давати посилання на них. Тут постає, мабуть, інше питання, за яке в основному тілі питання почали б казати, що занадто відкрите до інтерпретацій (і я їх розумію і підтримую, тому задам в коментарях): чи є сенс просто почати використовувати "пірнок" і не паритися? Наскільки виправданий такий неологізм.

Comment: В цьому я навряд чи вам порадник. Це дійсно дуже суб'єктивно. Слово нейтральне, не лайливе, нормам словотворення відповідає. Якщо орієнтуватися на значення [**неологізм**](http://sum.in.ua/s/neologhizm) в СУМ, особливо на наведений там приклад *"Неологізми, новотвори родяться щодня (Максим Рильський, III, 1956, 75)"*, то чому ні? Мова - живий організм. Принаймні, я жодних застережень не бачу.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko і я не бачу! Дякую.

Answer (score 3):

**Пірнання** ([Стаття в СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pirnannja)). Єдиний нюанс, якого може бракувати, якщо вживати без контексту, це доконаність/неповторюваність, але це так само справедливо і для `занурювання`, до того ж приклади вживання слова в СУМ відповідають обом відповідникам `dive` і `diving` (або рос. `нырок` и `ныряние`)

Comment: «Але це так само справедливо і для *занурювання*» — для *[занур**юв**ання](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31071&page=1013)* справедливо, а от для *[занурення](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31067&page=1013)* — по-моєму, ні. *Занурення* — це, по-моєму, якраз одноразове.

Comment: @Sasha @Miroshko от власне! Занурення - це одноразове. Я ж навмисно окреслив це відповідним рядом: `стрибати - стрибання - стрибок`.

Comment: @P.Vovk, спало на думку, що є низка слів на *-ання*, що поєднують значення як для багаторазової, так і для одноразової дії, напр.: *зітхання*, *зізнання*, *пирхання*, *позіхання*, *бажання*. Може, все ж, так само і з *пірнанням*?

Comment: «Пірнання» сприймається як серія занурень чи заняття пірнанням. Якщо йдеться про разову дію, чи не краще сказати «занурення» (не «занурювання», що позначає тривале чи багаторазове занурення)?

Comment: @PYPY якщо б ви зробили аналіз, може, навіть проаналізували, що краще, неолоґізм "пірнок", чи існуюче занурення, або запропонували би компроміс, на кшталт, "використовувати занурення в офіційних документах, а пірнок - там, де необов’язкове дотримання правопису" - було б непоганою відповіддю.